# a question about multivariable integral!

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

If $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer in $x$, evaluate the integral$$ \iint_{R} \lfloor x+y \rfloor ~ \mathrm{d}x~ \mathrm{d}y$$where $R= \{(x,y)| 1\leq x\leq 3, 2\leq y\leq 5\}$. This question is in my textbook, but I have no idea about how to solve it. Does somebody help me solve this question, or can somebody give me some hints about it?

Comment: Divide the region into a few spots where $[x + y]$ is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide region into smaller where $[x+y]$ is constant, you can try this way:

1) $[x+y]=3$ in $D=\{(x,y): 1\leq x < 2, 2\leq y \leq 3-x\}$, so let's calculate

$\int_{1}^{2} \int_{2}^{3-x}[x+y] dxdy=\int_{1}^{2} \int_{2}^{3-x}3 dxdy$

2)$[x+y]=4$ in $D=\{(x,y): 1\leq x < 3, 3\leq y \leq 4-x\}$, calculate:

$\int_{1}^{3} \int_{3}^{4-x}[x+y] dxdy=\int_{1}^{3} \int_{3}^{4-x}4 dxdy$

The same with other cases $[x+y]=5,6,7,8$, next add all integral- it's the result.